# Hyperledger fabric client ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

While connecting first network (byfn) to node client with fabric-client package I'm getting below error

code : https://pastebin.com/SFEVXXvM

`

```
'use strict';
/*
* Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
/*
 * Chaincode Invoke
 */

var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');
var fs = require('fs');
//
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

// setup the fabric network
var channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');

const peer_tls = "../network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt";
const peer_tls_data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, peer_tls));

var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051',{
    pem : Buffer.from(peer_tls_data).toString(),
    'ssl-target-name-override' : "peer0.org1.example.com"
});
channel.addPeer(peer);

const orderer_tls = "../network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt";
const orderer_tls_data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, orderer_tls));
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpcs://localhost:7050',{
    pem : Buffer.from(orderer_tls_data).toString(),
    'ssl-target-name-override' : "orderer.example.com"
})

channel.addOrderer(order);

//
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store');
console.log('Store path:'+store_path);
var tx_id = null;

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

    // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('user2', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded user2 from persistence');
        member_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to get user2.... run registerUser.js');
    }

    // get a transaction id object based on the current user assigned to fabric client
    tx_id = fabric_client.newTransactionID();
    console.log("Assigning transaction_id: ", tx_id._transaction_id);

    // createCar chaincode function - requires 5 args, ex: args: ['CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom'],
    // changeCarOwner chaincode function - requires 2 args , ex: args: ['CAR10', 'Dave'],
    // must send the proposal to endorsing peers
    var request = {
        //targets: let default to the peer assigned to the client
        chaincodeId: 'mycc',
        fcn: 'post',
        args: [JSON.stringify(
            {
                "Taxable": "false",
                "BillAddr": {
                  "Id": "16",
                  "Line1": "789 Sugar Lane",
                  "City": "Middlefield",
                  "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA",
                  "PostalCode": "94303",
                  "Lat": "37.4530553",
                  "Long": "-122.1178261"
                },
                "Job": "false",
                "BillWithParent": "false",
                "Balance": "75",
                "BalanceWithJobs": "75",
                "CurrencyRef": {
                  "value": "USD",
                  "name": "United States Dollar"
                },
                "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print",
                "Id": "16",
                "MetaData": {
                  "CreateTime": "2021-09-12T17:11:27-07:00",
                  "LastUpdatedTime": "2021-09-18T15:18:18-07:00"
                },
                "GivenName": "Kathy",
                "FamilyName": "Kuplis",
                "FullyQualifiedName": "Kookies by Kathy",
                "CompanyName": "Kookies by Kathy",
                "DisplayName": "Kookies by Kathy",
                "PrintOnCheckName": "Kookies by Kathy",
                "Active": "true",
                "PrimaryPhone": {
                  "FreeFormNumber": "(650) 555-7896"
                },
                "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
                  "Address": "qbwebsamplecompany@yahoo.com"
                }
              }
        ), "Customer", "16"],
        chainId: 'mychannel',
        txId: tx_id
    };
    
    // send the transaction proposal to the peers
    return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
}).then((results) => {
    var proposalResponses = results[0];
    var proposal = results[1];
    let isProposalGood = false;
    if (proposalResponses && proposalResponses[0].response &&
        proposalResponses[0].response.status === 200) {
            isProposalGood = true;
            console.log('Transaction proposal was good');
        } else {
            console.error('Transaction proposal was bad');
        }
    if (isProposalGood) {
        console.log(util.format(
            'Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - %s, message - "%s"',
            proposalResponses[0].response.status, proposalResponses[0].response.message));

        // build up the request for the orderer to have the transaction committed
        var request = {
            proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
            proposal: proposal
        };

        // set the transaction listener and set a timeout of 30 sec
        // if the transaction did not get committed within the timeout period,
        // report a TIMEOUT status
        var transaction_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID(); //Get the transaction ID string to be used by the event processing
        var promises = [];

        var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(request);
        promises.push(sendPromise); //we want the send transaction first, so that we know where to check status

        // get an eventhub once the fabric client has a user assigned. The user
        // is required bacause the event registration must be signed
        let event_hub = channel.newChannelEventHub(peer);

        // using resolve the promise so that result status may be processed
        // under the then clause rather than having the catch clause process
        // the status
        let txPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let handle = setTimeout(() => {
                event_hub.unregisterTxEvent(transaction_id_string);
                event_hub.disconnect();
                resolve({event_status : 'TIMEOUT'}); //we could use reject(new Error('Trnasaction did not complete within 30 seconds'));
            }, 3000);
            event_hub.registerTxEvent(transaction_id_string, (tx, code) => {
                // this is the callback for transaction event status
                // first some clean up of event listener
                clearTimeout(handle);

                // now let the application know what happened
                var return_status = {event_status : code, tx_id : transaction_id_string};
                if (code !== 'VALID') {
                    console.error('The transaction was invalid, code = ' + code);
                    resolve(return_status); // we could use reject(new Error('Problem with the tranaction, event status ::'+code));
                } else {
                    console.log('The transaction has been committed on peer ' + event_hub.getPeerAddr());
                    resolve(return_status);
                }
            }, (err) => {
                //this is the callback if something goes wrong with the event registration or processing
                reject(new Error('There was a problem with the eventhub ::'+err));
            },
                {disconnect: true} //disconnect when complete
            );
            event_hub.connect();

        });
        promises.push(txPromise);

        return Promise.all(promises);
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...');
        throw new Error('Failed to send Proposal or receive valid response. Response null or status is not 200. exiting...');
    }
}).then((results) => {
    console.log('Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed');
    // check the results in the order the promises were added to the promise all list
    if (results && results[0] && results[0].status === 'SUCCESS') {
        console.log('Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.');
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to order the transaction. Error code: ' + results[0].status);
    }

    if(results && results[1] && results[1].event_status === 'VALID') {
        console.log('Successfully committed the change to the ledger by the peer');
    } else {
        console.log('Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::'+results[1].event_status);
    }
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Failed to invoke successfully :: ' + err);
});


function marshalArgs(args) {
    if (!args) {
        return args;
    }

    if (typeof args === 'string') {
        return [args];
    }

    //let snakeArgs = converter.camelToSnakeCase(args);

    if (Array.isArray(args)) {
        arr = [];
        for(i=0;i<args.length;i++){
            let arg = marshalArgs(args[i]);
            arr.push(arg);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    if (typeof args === 'object') {
        return [JSON.stringify(objToString(args))];
    }
}
/*
 * Convert all the properties of a object to String 
 */  

function objToString(myObj){
    Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key){
      typeof myObj[key] == 'object' ? objToString(myObj[key]) : myObj[key]= String(myObj[key]);
    });
    return myObj;
}
```

`

> Assigning transaction_id:  ea8291e609e66b5a2312cce32e432dcc661e09109876e5dea692a12dd6f95b62
>
> Transaction proposal was good
>
> Successfully sent Proposal and received ProposalResponse: Status - 200, message - ""
> The transaction was invalid, code = ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
>
> Send transaction promise and event listener promise have completed
>
> Successfully sent transaction to the orderer.
>
> Transaction failed to be committed to the ledger due to ::ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

This likely occurred because when you need multiple peers from different orgs to have the transaction be sent to, the endorsement policy is AND.

You can set `request`'s target to all the peers specified in the endorsement policy and that should fix this